# How do I have different colliders against different objects? Unity

Tags: collision-detection, unityscript, unity

Say for example I have a ball, I want the sphere collider to be a certain radius when it comes into contact with one material (material A in diagram) and a different size when it comes into contact with another material (material C in diagram). How would I go about doing this? (Diagram attached)

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create two empty child GameObjects of material C that work in different layers. One child has a sphere collider with a radius of e.g. 5, reacting to colliders in the layer "One" and one child using a sphere collider with the radius of 10 working in layer "Two".
The colliders that react only to the collider with the radius 5 just only react to the layer "One". With layer "Two" the same.

[image: Layer One collider]

[image: Layer Two collider]

Now uncheck the interaction between "One" and "Two" in the physics manager:

[image: Physics manager]

Now for material A set the layer you want to use with the colliders and
the problem is solved.